# How can I access a div within a td when I click on the entire row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed tableMyAssignment">
<tbody>
<tr class="tablerows">
<td class="recordstd"><div class="Circle_onoff"></div></td>
<td class="recordstd columncolor columntext">7th grade poetry </td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">7th</td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">English</td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">13</td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">R.L.8.1,R.I.8.2</td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">Jane Doe</td>
<td class="recordstd columntext">1/2/2014</td>
</tr>
```

How can I access the Div which is class of 'Circle_onoff' when I click on the entire row using jQuery?
I can access the div by clicking only on it. But I want to access it when I click on the row.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.Circle_onoff');` inside click handler of any TDs. Now you'd have better to provide which handler you are using. If click handler is set on TR level, just use find()

Answer (score 0):

Give the td in which your div is situated an ID and should help you to achieve what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Generally, there is no reason to add ID attribute to any element

Comment: @A.Wolff but it's kind of a simple way to solve the problem not using any code

Comment: Is not simple way because you need to code some logic to get unique IDs so it is more a complicated way than an easy one. Better is to use any transversal method to target specific element. Because ya, most of the time TABLE content is dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tablerows').click(function() {
      $(this).find('div.Circle_onoff').html();  
    });`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tableMyAssignment tr').click(function(){
     alert($(this).find('.Circle_onoff').html());
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Q2h/)**

Answer (score 0):

write click event of tr like

```
$(document).on('click', '.tablerows', function() {
    //do operations here
    $(this).find('.Circle_onoff').html();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the closest() function: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

By using a onClick handler, you can do what you want to achieve. Here is the relevant code-part:

```
<script>
    $("table").on( "click", function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest(tr).find('.Circle_onoff');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplying the color style to the div text:

```
$('.tablerows').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.Circle_onoff').css("color", "red");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/macmessa/uNy99/

Comment: This one was i Was looking for thanks.. Need to apply css on background for this div... thanks a lot :)